# PHP result into JavaScript with query

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in Object-Oriented Programming so it would be nice if someone can help me ^^

i got this JS function rn:

```js
function confirmDel(element) {
  let confirmDel = confirm("u sure u want to delete?");
  
  if (confirmDel) {
    console.log(element);
    window.location.href=="formprocess.php?firmadelete=";
    alert(deleted");
  }
  else{ 
    alert("deleting canceled");
  }
}
```

and in my HTML i got

```html
  <a 
    class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
    href="formprocess.php?firmadelete=<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>"
  ><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></a>
</td>
```

Maybe u see my try. I want to ask "U sure u want to delete?" and if I'm pressing "yes" it should bring me to the href `formprocess.php?firmadelete=<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>`

How I can translate the $result['FirmenID'] into the JS script?

Greetings from Germany
~Lampi

Comment: Please proofread your question. There's a lot of txtspk and other mistakes that make the question more difficult to read. See also: [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/#presentation)

Comment: "im a newbie in object oriented programming" — There's nothing OOP about this. It's highly procedural.

Comment: Your code won't execute because it has syntax errors.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should never design your HTTP request in a way that a `GET` request would delete something. A browser might try to prefetch the page `<a>` is linking to (`href="formprocess.php?firmadelete=<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>"`)  resulting in data being deleted without any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the javascript is in a separate JS file and not just inline in the HTML itself (which would let you just add the same PHP you're using for adding it to the href), the easiest way to do this would probably be to just add a data attribute to the HTML element and then use JS to read the value from that.

If `element` passed in is the link that was clicked on, you could do something like this in the HTML:

```html
<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="formprocess.php?firmadelete=<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>" data-id="<?= $result['FirmenID']; ?>>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
</a>
```

and this in the JS:

```js
function confirmDel(element) {
...
if (confirmDel) {
    console.log(element);
    const id = element.getAttribute('data-id');
    window.location.href == "formprocess.php?firmadelete=" + id;
...
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**href**
a link always needs a href, so I changed it to '#' (which is the top of the page).

**onclick**
I use click-event (onclick) to call the function confirmDel.  The event.preventDefault(); function is called to cancel the href.

**data-id**
The FirmId is saved in data-id. The possible special characters are escaped with the htmlspecialchars function, this is not neccecery if you are certain that FirmenID is always a number.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="#" onclick="confirmDel(this); event.preventDefault();" data-id="<?= htmlspecialchars($result['FirmenID'], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8"); ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i> testme</a></td>
```

**JavaScript**
The only thing that is changed in the JavaScript code is adding the FirmenID behind the URL. This is done by retrieving the id by accessing data-id (*.dataset.id).

**Alert**
The Alert box will never be displayed, since the URL of the page changes. If you want the URL to be executed in the background instead, please check [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
function confirmDel(element) {
  let confirmDel = confirm("u sure u want to delete?");
  if (confirmDel) {
    console.log(element);
    window.location.href="formprocess.php?firmadelete=" + element.dataset.id;
    alert("deleted");
    }
  else{ 
    alert("deleting canceled");
    }
  }
```

Comment: `href a link always needs a href, so I changed it to '#' (which is the top of the page).` That indicates that it shouldn't be a `<a>` element at all. Even `#` references something: The same URL with the fragment `#`, so if the intent of the `<a>` is not to link the URL it is on then `<a>` is the wrong thing to use.

Comment: @t.niese You are right, but I think it doesn't help to mention those details to a beginner. It's probably better that he gets working code and learns from it, than pointing out all the things that can be done better.

Comment: That helped me alot! Thx for that fast solution ^^

and also sry for my bad grammar :D